# Writing For Loop or Split function to separate data from Master data frame into smaller data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, split

I am once again asking for your help and guidance! Super duper novice here so I apologize in advance for not explaining things properly or my general lack of knowledge for something that feels like it should be easy to do.

[image]

I have sets of compounds in one "master" list that need to be separated into smaller list. I want to be able to do this with a "for loop" or some iterative function so I am not changing the numbers for each list. I want to separate the compounds based off of the column "Run.Number" (there are 21 Run.Numbers)

Step 1: Load the programs needed and open File containing "Master List"

```
# tMSMS List separation
#Load library packages
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(readr) #loading the csv's
library(dplyr) #data manipulation
library(magrittr) #forward pipe
library(openxlsx) #open excel sheets
library(Rcpp) #got this from an error code while trying to open excel sheets


#STEP 1: open file
S1_MasterList<- read.xlsx("/Users/owner/Documents/Research/Yurok/Bioassay/Bioassay Data/220410_tMSMS_neg_R.xlsx")
```

Step 2: Currently, to go through each list, I have to change the "i" value for each iteration. And I also must change the name manually (Ctrl+F), by replacing "S2_Export_1" with "S2_Export_2" and so on as I move from list to list.  Also, when making the smaller list, there are a handful of columns containing data that need to be removed from the “Master List”.   The specific format of column names are so it will be compatible with LC-MS software. This list is saved as a .csv file, again for compatibility with LC-MS software

```
#STEP 2: Iterative 
#Replace: S2_Export_1
i=1
(S2_Separate<- S1_MasterList[which(S1_MasterList$Run.Number == i), ])
%>%
(S2_Export_1<-data.frame(S2_Separate$On, 
                         S2_Separate$`Prec..m/z`, 
                         S2_Separate$Z, 
                         S2_Separate$`Ret..Time.(min)`, 
                         S2_Separate$`Delta.Ret..Time.(min)`, 
                         S2_Separate$Iso..Width,
                         S2_Separate$Collision.Energy))
(colnames(S2_Export_1)<-c("On", "Prec. m/z", "Z","Ret. Time (min)", "Delta Ret. Time (min)", "Iso. Width", "Collision Energy"))
(write.csv(S2_Export_1, "/Users/owner/Documents/Research/Yurok/Bioassay/Bioassay Data/Runs/220425_neg_S2_Export_1.csv", row.names = FALSE))
```

Results: The output should look like this image provided below, and for this one particular data frame called "Master List", there should be 21 smaller data frames. I also want the data frames to be named S2_Export_1, S2_Export_2, S2_Export_3, S2_Export_4, etc.

[image]

Comment: You are more likely to receive an answer if you provide a **minimal** reproducible example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First, select only required columns (consider processing/renaming [non-syntactic names](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#non-syntactic) first to avoid extra work downstream):

```
s1_sub <- select(S1_MasterList, Sample.Number, On, `Prec..m/z`, Z, 
                `Ret..Time.(min)`, `Delta.Ret..Time.(min)`,
                 Iso..Width, Collision.Energy)
```

Then split `s1_sub` into a list of dataframes with `split()`

```
s1_split <- split(s1_sub, s1_sub$Sample.Number)
```

Finally, name the resulting list of dataframes with `setNames()`:

```
s1_split <- setNames(s1_split, paste0("S2_export_", seq_along(s1_split))
```